# php include not working for existing files

Tags: php, include

I have recently changed my homemade framework to store the template files in the theme folder instead of a general template folder. The problem is now that I have done so, for some reason my include()'s point to the correct files but don't work. However, for some reason the theme templates include() works.

I receive these errors:

```
Warning: require(lib/themes/original/templates/en/home/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/stretch045/public_html/lib/theme/original/templateen.php on line 27

Warning: require(lib/themes/original/templates/en/home/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/stretch045/public_html/lib/theme/original/templateen.php on line 27

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'lib/themes/original/templates/en/home/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/stretch045/public_html/lib/theme/original/templateen.php on line 27
```

I believe the last one might explain it, but I don't understand what the stuff in the brackets is supposed to mean as it isn't a path I have on my shared server.

If necessary I will provide code, but I don't see how that could be the problem as the path is correct.

Comment: The path is obviously not correct

Comment: use the fullpath `/something/lib/themes/` instead of relative `lib/themes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are trying to include the files from the folder `themes` when it maybe should be `theme`, at least that's what I understand from your errors:

```
Warning: require(lib/themes/original/templates/en/home/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/stretch045/public_html/lib/theme/original/templateen.php on line 27
```

Here it is clearly that the file '/home/stretch045/public_html/lib/**theme**/original/templateen.php' tries to include the file 'lib/**themes**/original/templates/en/home/index.php'.

The fact that you are using relative paths shouldn't be a problem if the entry point for your framework is `/home/stretch045/public_html/index.php`, because the documentation for [include()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.include.php) applies for `require()` method too, therefor it knows to check if the file exists relatively to the current working directory, also relatively to the calling script's own directory

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because the file could not be found.

You are using a relative path in your require statement. This is especially problematic if an included file includes further files using a relative path (because PHP uses the path relative to the script being executed and not the file containing the include/require statement).

PHP tries to find relative referenced files using the `include_path`, i.e. `.` relative to the file which is executed and also in /usr/lib/php and in /usr/local/lib/php (i.e., /usr/lib/php/lib/themes/original/templates/en/home/index.php and /usr/local/lib/php/lib/themes/original/templates/en/home/index.php). None of these exist.

So, use the correct relative path (e.g., always based on the current script path by using `require(__DIR__.'/PATH');`) OR use an absolute path in your require statement OR add your basepath to `include_path` (`:` is the path separator).

Comment: Then why does it work for my theme and why did it work previously with the only change being it getting the theme name from db??

Comment: based on your initial description you also moved files into different directories, this breaks relative paths!